# Why does Desmos not plot $ \sqrt{\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + \sqrt{2} $?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, math-software, wolfram-alpha, desmos

I am working on the following problem:

**I need to find the points above the line $l:y=-x$ for which it holds that the distance to $l$ is $\sqrt{2}$ greater than the distance to the origin.**

I worked out a way to calculate the distance from a point to the line $l$:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}.
$$
And then obviously the distance from a point to the origin is:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$
I then tried to plot the function:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + \sqrt{2}
$$
in **Desmos and wolframalpha and both plots gave me nothing**...
I even tried to plot just:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
for which I know the line $y=x$ should be a solution, but this didn't plot anything either.

I'm not sure what is causing this. **Why are Desmos and wolframalpha not able to Plot the curves ?** Any ideas?
Many thanks,
Hugo

Comment: More surprising is that wolfram alpha fails as well , in the second equation , removing the square roots should save the day. In the first equation , we need a bit more effort to find a suitable equation.

Comment: There is no $(x,y)$ pair of real numbers for which the equation is true, thus no graph. It is implied that $\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}>x^2+y^2$ which implies that $(x-y)^2<0$.

Comment: OP has made a mistake to add the $\sqrt{2}$ on the wrong side , @JohnWaylandBales , when that is corrected , we will get the locus ! I have added Images to my Earlier Answer , to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PROBLEM :

There is 1 MAJOR Issue ( & 1 MINOR Issue ) with your formulation , which is why neither DESMOS nor Wolfram will give the necessary graph.

(MAJOR) Distance to Origin ( $A$ ) is always more than ( or Equal to ) Distance to the line ( $B$ ) , in the given Case.
Hence , when you add $\sqrt{2}$ to $A$ , you are making it even larger than $B$ & there is no Point which will work out.

You should rather add $\sqrt{2}$ to $B$ to make the Correct formulation.

This Image highlights that Issue :

[image: NO POINT]

(MINOR) You are using $\sqrt{(x+y)^2}$ when trying to get $B$ magnitude , which is a little round-about.
Instead , you should use the More Direct $|x+y|$ & check that.

OUTPUT :

When I made those Changes , I got the necessary graph :

[image: CORRECT LOCUS]

I used Wolfram Online Tool here. DESMOS too will give that Plot without issues now.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you want to plot seems to be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{|x+y|+2}{\sqrt2}$ which should scream parabolas with focus $(0,0)$ and directrices $x+y+2=0$ and $-(x+y)+2=0$ at you.

Repeated squaring indeed yields $\frac14(x^2+y^2-\frac{(x+y+2)^2}2)(x^2+y^2-\frac{(x+y-2)^2}2)=0$ which plots as [two parabolas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0V3Q.png).

However, squaring can add solutions, and the parts around the vertices $(\pm\frac12,\pm\frac12)$ bounded by the intersection with the line $|x+y|=0$ are not on the original plot, precisely because those belong to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{|x+y|-2}{\sqrt2}$ (from the title) which doesn't have points as John Wayland Bales shows in a comment to the question.